# How to create div with one triangular side in Reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to make a header like the following image, How can I create such UI in React js.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could try doing it with clip-path, more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Also I recommend using this website to get used to it/create stuff easier:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
e.g. The first shape you've got there could be done with:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

With the rest of them, feel free to experiment.